# Share model class between custom packages dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created 2 packages outside `lib` folder called : `authentication_repository` and `user_repository` to handle network requests.

This is my project structure :

```
├── lib
├── packages
│ ├── authentication_repository
│ └── user_repository
```

Since both repo needs `User` class I would like to provide them the same source file but I don't know how to do it.

Now each repo has its own `User` class and this is a problem because when I import them inside the same file Flutter doesn't know which `user.dart` file to use, if the one defined inside `authentication_repository` or the other one defined in `user_repository` .
Each repo has its own `pubspec.yaml` file so maybe I could start from here?

Some suggested me to create a new repo called `models` and define here the `User` class, then both `authentication_repository` and `user_repository` will depend from `models` so they should be able to access the same file. This idea sounds good to me but I don't know how to do it.

EDIT :

I created a new repo called `models` with `User` class and models file :

```
class User extends Equatable {
  const User(this.id);

  final String id;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id];
}
```

And models file :

```
library models;

export './src/user.dart' show User;
```

Now how can I add this package to the other 2 repo? This is `models/pubspec.yaml` :

```
name: models
description: Dart package which manages the user domain.
version : ^1.0.0
publish_to: none

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  equatable: ^2.0.0
```

Now I think I should be able to add it to other `pubspec.yaml` file like this one inside `user_repository` :

```
name: user_repository
description: Dart package which manages the user domain.
publish_to: none

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  models: ^1.0.0
```

But receiving this error on `models/pubspec.yaml` :
`Error on line 3, column 11 of pubspec.yaml: Invalid version number: Could not parse "^1.0.0"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simpler than you think. Just create a new package `models` in the same way you created other packages. In created package you will see `models.dart`. This file will imported by other packages like

```
import 'package:models/models.dart
```

In the lib folder create new folder `src` and add `user.dart` file with your `User` class into `user.dart`.
To make it accessible from package in your root file `models.dart` add these lines

```
library models;
export './src/user.dart' show User;
```

Do not forget to add the package as a dependency for other packages in their pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  models:
    path: [RELATIVE_PATH_TO_PACKAGE]
```

RELATIVE_PATH_TO_PACKAGE - is the path relatively to your other packages. If you place `models` package in your `packages` folder, then in pubspec.yaml of `authentication_repository`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  models:
    path: '../models'
```

Comment: "Do not forget to add the package as a dependency for other packages in their pubspec.yaml."
How can I do this?  I gave a version to my model package but can't import as dependency inside the other packages, I will edit my question

Comment: Thank you mate, very clear explanation. Is it the same if instead of using path: '../packages/models' I use path: '../models' ? Seems working

Comment: Yes., exactly. I corrected the answer - it should be '../models'.